# Codeigniter - Error - There is no data to update

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I was to update my database but I get the error, "no data to update".  Here is my script;

I have created a simple toggle to up update the database. The toggle makes the user active (is_active=1) or inactive (is_active=0). The problem I am encountering is that although the object is change from 1 to 0 or 0 to 1, when I pass it to the model, it comes back with the error, "There is no data to update". The method is as follows;

namespace App\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Entities\User;

class Users extends \App\Controllers\BaseController
{
private $model;

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->model = new \App\Models\UserModel;
}



      public function toggle_user_is_active($id)
      {
      $users = $this->model->where('id', $id)->first();  // get the record

     // if the current user is ACTIVE, then set it to DEACTIVE
     if ($users->is_active == 1) {
         $users->is_active = 0; 
         $this->model->save($users));  // gives an error, nothing to update
         return redirect()->to('/Admin/Users/index')
                     ->with('info', 'Success - User deactivated');
     } else {
         // if the current used is ACTIVE(1), change to INACTIVE(0)
         $users->is_active = 1; 
         $this->model->save($users); // same error as above
         return redirect()->to('/Admin/Users/index')
                     ->with('info', 'Success - User Activated');
     }
 } // end method

 }
```

The really strange thing is this is a copy of another method that works perfectly as follows;

```
 namespace App\Controllers\Admin;

 use App\Entities\CategoryEntity;
 use App\Entities\PostEntity;

class Post extends \App\Controllers\BaseController
{
private $model;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->model = new \App\Models\PostModel;
    $this->CategoryModel = new \App\Models\CategoryModel;
    $auth = new \App\Libraries\Authentication;
    $this->current_user = $auth->getCurrentUser();
}

public function toggle_post_is_published($post_id)
{
    $post = $this->model->where('post_id', $post_id)->first();
    // if the current post is PUBLISHED, then set it to UNPUBLISHED
    if ($post->post_is_published == 1) {
        echo
        $post->post_is_published = 0;
        $this->model->save($post);
        return redirect()->to('/admin/post/post_index')
                         ->with('info', 'Success - Post unpublished');
    } else {
        // if the current post is UNPUBLISHED, then set it to PUBLISHED
        $post->post_is_published = 1;
        $this->model->save($post);
        return redirect()->to('/admin/post/post_index')
                         ->with('info', 'Success - Post published');
    }
}
} // end class
```

Comment: What debugging have you tried?  Have you checked if `$users` is set as expected? In the 2nd controller you set up `$this->model`, but not in the first, or at least it is not shown here.  So what is it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I finally figured it out.  In my UserModel I did not add 'is_active' to  protected $allowedFields .  I have now added 'is_active' to the allowedFields and it works.

Comment: Yes! The error is deceptive. The error shouldn't be "no data to update" because that makes you think the lookup failed on the primary key. A much better error message would be "update not allowed". If it said *that* then somebody would immediately think about allowedFields.

Comment: I laughed when I read your solution, because I didn't assign the allowedFields too!! haha.. but obviously you made my day! and thanks anyway!!

Answer (score 0):

Have you declare your model, because look like you use $this- >model but not setup your model in your constructor or other method.

Comment: Yes, I have included the model.  I just updated to code to reflect that above.

Comment: I even tried including the primary key just before save() like $users->id = $id; and $users->is_active = 0; but same error

Comment: Had you vardump your user result ?

Comment: appreciated but I already noted the fix/solution below. Thank you!