# There is no data to insert. in SYSTEMPATH\BaseModel.php on line 729

Tags: php, codeigniter-4

Particulars in Model

```
protected $allowedFields = ['page_title','page_status'];

public function store($data){
   try {
         if($this->insert($data,false)=== true){
            return $this->getInsertID();
         }else{
           return $this->errors();
       }  
     } catch (Exception $e) {
            return $e->getMessage();
   }
}
```

Particulars in Controller

```
$page_data_to_add=array('post_title'=>$page_title,'post_status'=>$page_status);

$data_added=$this->page->store($page_data_to_add);

Both these variables $page_title and $page_status has value
```

Trying to add data.Same function is working in other models and controller.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Codeigniter - Error - There is no data to update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67457107/codeigniter-error-there-is-no-data-to-update)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question since it was caused by a **typo**. This one was resolved in a way less likely to help future readers.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in the controller data array

allowedfields are page_title,page_status

but in controller data array is different

$page_data_to_add=array('post_title'=>$page_title,'post_status'=>$page_status);

it will be

$page_data_to_add=array('page_title'=>$page_title,'page_status'=>$page_status);